# Manage running Java apps remotely

Tags: java, monitoring, vert.x

We have several Java standalone applications (in form of Jar files) running on multiple servers. These applications mainly read and stream data between systems. We are using Java 8 mainly in our development. I was put in charge recently. My main function is to manage and maintain these apps.

Currently, I check these apps manually by accessing these servers, check if the app is running, and sometimes run some database queries to see if the app started pulling data. My problem is that in many cases, some of these apps fail and shutdown due to data issue or edge cases without anyone noticing. We need some monitoring and application recovery in place.

We don't have docker infrastructure in place. We plan to implement docker in the future, but for now this is not an option.

After research, the following are options I thought of or solutions I tried:

1. Have the apps create a socket client which sends a heartbeat to a monitoring app (which needs to be developed). I am keeping this as my last option.
2. I tried to use Eclipse Vertx to wrap the apps into Verticles. Then create a web view that can show me status and other info. After several tries, the apps fail to parse the data correctly (might be due to my lack of understanding to Vertx library).
3. Have a third party solution that does this, but I have no idea what solutions are out there. I am open for suggestions.

My requirements are:

1. Proper monitoring of the apps running and their status.
2. In case of failure, the app should start again while notifying the admin/developer.

I am willing to develop a solution or implement a third party one. I need you guidance on this.

Thank you.

Comment: You are missing out important information. What do your apps use to work with (i.e some kind of framework), where are they deployed, etc etc. Please provide these in order for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: I agree with @akortex . For example, spring-boot already has a built-in endpoint that you could use to monitor your application, docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/… (Micronaut too, docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#healthEndpoint)

Comment: admlz635 and akortex, we are using plain java app. No Spring-Boot is being used. I will check Spring-Boot as an option and check docs url you've sent.

Comment: @user16320675 from my understanding of Watchdog github readme, it is mainly to protect the app from "runaway loops and stalled I/O". I don't think this meets my requirements.

Comment: @user16320675 I was looking at this "https://github.com/offbynull/watchdog". After further search, I found "https://docs.datadoghq.com/watchdog/". The latter seems promising. I will check it in more details.

Comment: @admlz635 I check spring boot and also found spring-boot-admin which answers my needs. I will need to add some customizations, but so far we finished a rough estimation and plan on how are we going to implement it. Please post your answer so I can mark this as solved. My thanks for everyone for your help. We found many things that will be useful for our task and we might use combination of more than one. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @mohd874 done. I've added more info about custom health checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [spring-boot-actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints) (see health). It comes with a built-in endpoint that has some health checks(depending on your spring-boot project), but you can create [your own](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.health.writing-custom-health-indicators) as well.

Then, doing a http request to http://{host}:{port}/{context}/actuator/health (replace with yours), you could see those health checks status and also use the response status code to monitor your application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of Java Service Wrappers? Not a full management functionality, however it would monitor for JVM crashes and out of memory conditions and restart your application for sure. Alerting should also be possible.

There is a small comparison table here: https://yajsw.sourceforge.io/#mozTocId284533

So some basic monitoring and management is included already. If you need more, I suggest using JMX (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javamanagement.html) or Prometheus (https://prometheus.io/ and  https://github.com/prometheus/client_java)

Comment: Yajsw seems good and will keep it in mind, but it does not provide the ability to monitor the app remotly.